# VueJS and browser back button

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

No it is not the usual question :-D I know that I need to watch route change.. this a different one.

I use VueJS 3 and router. When I navigate in my app I go from one component to another or moving in the component (changing data) and I want to get back by browser button sometimes one back sometimes two backs and the page is not displayed. Literary display:none. In Vue debugger I can see all the data. I can see all the HTML elements but they have display:none

The full reload works as expected. I can go back in the browser history the data are changing but not displaying with full reload everything is displayed correctly.

Honestly I do not know where to start looking. No errors. And it is not a first project that I am doing but this for the first time I experience this.

I can share anything what you want to explore as the code is not a secrete but I cant see the point now flood it here with the whole code.

Comment: I got it! JQuery mobile.. not sure whats exactly wrong but when I removed it from my code it works. If anybody can explain it or have any experience. I use 1.4.5 version